# Why if and else both condition executing at same time in JavaScript | If and Else Condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, if-statement

Why If and else condition work both in JavaScript. `if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)`

I am working on php MVC project.

I created a profile edit page in background JavaScript `If` and `Else` both code executing. profile edit Successfully but else code work and it's show error "Sorry, this content isn't available right now".

why this `else` condition work??

- same This code work in login and registration page.
- save in local file and run than it work :-
  [online code](https://jsfiddle.net/uttamnath/0y1aw972/20/)

`Code`

```
 document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Email").value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)) {
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.remove("active_success");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.remove("active_denger");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").innerHTML = "Loading...";
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").classList.remove("active");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").disabled = true;

            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_F_Name").disabled = true;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_L_Name").disabled = true;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Email").disabled = true;

            var f_name = document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_F_Name").value,
                l_name = document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_L_Name").value,
                email = document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Email").value;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "Api/ProfileEdit", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { // this one if executing 
                    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if (json.Status == "Ok") {
                        window.location.href = "Profile"; // it also work 
                    } else {
                        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.remove("active_success");
                        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
                        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = json.Message;
                    }
                } else { // this one else executing 
                    document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
                    document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = "Sorry, this content isn't available right now"; // this message show 
                }
            }
            xhr.send("F_Name=" + f_name + "&L_Name=" + l_name + "&Email=" + email);
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").innerHTML = "Register";
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").classList.add("active");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").disabled = false;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_F_Name").disabled = false;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_L_Name").disabled = false;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Email").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = "Invalid Email Address!";
        }
    });
```

`return JSON`

```
{"Status":"Ok","Message":"Profile Edit Successfully!"}
```

`Output`

```
open profile page and 
error message:- "Sorry, this content isn't available right now"
```

[image]

help me!
Thank you!!

Comment: I have put a ```console.log()``` inside if block. It never executed. Are you sure the if block is working?

Comment: Online editor not support to call any api or url to get data. Just save local file and run this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readystatechange` event [fires multiple times.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)

```
Value   State       Description
0       UNSENT      Client has been created. open() not called yet.
1       OPENED      open() has been called.
2       HEADERS_RECEIVED    send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
3       LOADING     Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
4       DONE        The operation is complete.
```

Your

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
```

branch will only be entered into at the end of a request, if the request was successful. But earlier, while the request is still ongoing, other state changes will occur, and the `else` branch will be entered into.

Instead, only do anything if the readyState is 4 - and, when it is 4, you can parse the response, or populate the `#Profile_Edit_Msg` to say there was a problem.

Other improvements:

- Save the `Profile_Edit_Msg` in a variable instead of repetitively selecting it over and over again
- Use strict equality, [not sloppy equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)
- Use `.textContent` when assigning text to an element - only use `.innerHTML` when inserting HTML markup
- JSON is a particular format of a *string* that can be deserialized into an object or other value. `JSON.parse` does not return JSON - `JSON.parse` is called *with* a JSON-formatted string and returns an object. Call your `json` variable something else.
- `denger` looks misspelled - did you mean `danger`? (Typos are a common problem in programming - better to fix them earlier than later)

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
    }
    const profile = document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg");
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        const result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (result.Status === "Ok") {
            window.location.href = "Profile";
        } else {
            profile.classList.remove("active_success");
            profile.classList.add("active_denger");
            profile.innerHTML = json.Message;
        }
    } else {
        profile.classList.add("active_denger");
        profile.textContent = "Sorry, this content isn't available right now";
    }
};
```

You could also consider using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of XMLHttpRequest - `fetch` is a bit nicer to work with and has been supported in all modern browsers for ages.

Comment: Bro but in login and registration page it work why?

Comment: What do you mean, login and registration? This is the first time either of those have been mentioned

Comment: Can't really say without a clearer example of what's on each page, and what you mean by "work"